# access to external resources in the vert.x project

Tags: javascript, java, html, vert.x

I have a project in vert.x 3.4.1 that I compile in .jar and I want to access from that .jar to an image in the same path:

> - -- myProject
> - -------- project.jar
> - -------- config.json
> - -------- logo.png

in my project.jar i have some html pages, from this pages I want to access to logo.png, I don't wanna to set it into .jar

I tried to set a route special for that but not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `StaticHandler`, by default it looks for files in a `webroot` directory. Change your directory structure to:

```
myProject/
    project.jar
    config.json
    webroot/
        logo.png
```

Otherwise you can setup the [static handler to something other than the default web root](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_changing_the_web_root).